# I am trying to sent a record to my web server but the web server never gets hit

Tags: objective-c, asp.net-mvc

I have this little project 
I have some recipes that I want to share with my iPhone.
the database has  this fields
string id
string name
string recipe_text
byte[] image

so when I change it on the iPhone I call this function

```
+(void) sendRecipe:(BFRecipe *) recipe
{ 
    NSString * imageStringData = @"";
    if(recipe.recipeImage != nil)
        imageStringData = [UIImagePNGRepresentation(recipe.recipeImage) base64Encoding];

    NSDictionary * jsonRecord = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:recipe.recipeId,@"RecipeId",recipe.name,@"Name" ,recipe.recipeText,@"RecipeText",imageStringData,@"Item"  , nil];
    NSString *urlString =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults ] objectForKey:@"Host"],@"UpdateRecipeItem"];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest new];
    request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";

    NSData *jsonBodyData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonRecord options:kNilOptions error:nil];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [request setHTTPBody:jsonBodyData];
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config
                                                          delegate:nil
                                                     delegateQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];
    NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request
                                            completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data,
                                                                NSURLResponse * _Nullable response,
                                                                NSError * _Nullable error) {


                                                NSHTTPURLResponse *asHTTPResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *) response;

                                                // set a breakpoint on the last NSLog and investigate the response in the debugger

                                                // if you get data, you can inspect that, too. If it's JSON, do one of these:


                                            }];
    [task resume];
}
```

My MVC server has a function like this but it never gets called Why ?

```
public void UpdateRecipeImage(string id)
        {
            recipe_item item = Model.recipe_item.FirstOrDefault(ri => ri.recipe_id == new Guid(id));
....

.....

....
}
```

Comment: '' [HttpPost]
        public void UpdateRecipeItem(UpdateRecipeItem recipeItem)
        {
          
            try
            {
                recipe_item item = Model.recipe_item.FirstOrDefault(ri => ri.recipe_id == new Guid(recipeItem.RecipeId));

Answer (score 0):

I see problem with your calling part in objective-c code

```
 NSString *urlString =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults ] objectForKey:@"Host"],@"UpdateRecipeItem"];
```

Here you calling `@"UpdateRecipeItem"` but on mvc api you have `UpdateRecipeImage(string id)`

so problem is with your naming. Try to call proper api name that is `UpdateRecipeImage(string id)`

-OR-

If calling `@"UpdateRecipeItem"` is your attention, then post your mvc api code here with parameters. I am sure you're missing something for you api endpoint.

**UPDATE:** Based on your code shared in comment, try adding `[FromBody]` in you api method. Look at code below:

```
[HttpPost]
public void UpdateRecipeItem([FromBody] UpdateRecipeItem recipeItem)
{
    try
    {
        recipe_item item = Model.recipe_item.FirstOrDefault(ri => ri.recipe_id == new Guid(recipeItem.RecipeId));
```

Hope you understand. Happy Coding!

Comment: sorry I stuffed up the server code looks like this ''' [HttpPost]
        public void UpdateRecipeItem(UpdateRecipeItem recipeItem)
        {
          
            try
            {
                recipe_item item = Model.recipe_item.FirstOrDefault(ri => ri.recipe_id == new Guid(recipeItem.RecipeId));

Comment: look at the update in my answer, also monitor your http request with fiddler to verify if your request is correct, i mean url and parameters with body.

Comment: The interesting thing is that if recipe.recipeImage is nil the server gets called

Comment: then better share your whole recipe model in your question. may be there is a difference between what you have on server and what you are passing from client.